# Given any vector, how do you know which function space it belongs to?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

One thing I cannot wrap my head around is that there are so many many many conditions for different function spaces, how can you quickly determine which function space a vector/function belongs to?

I think there are 11 conditions for vectors space alone, Hilbert space adds one more, Banach space adds two more, Sobolev space adds....how many more I've lost count.

To know if a function belongs to a certain space, you will have to prove it satisfies each and every single condition for that function space. Even for a function simple as $f(x) = x$, you'd have to prove it for 11 + conditions and how can you ever remember all these conditions?

How do you remember all these conditions and is there a good way to know exactly which function space that a vector/function belongs to upon a glance?

Answer (score 1):

It looks vaguely like you're confusing the conditions for *something to be a vector space* with the conditions for something to be an *element* of a particular already known space.

For example, take the vector space of all real polynomials. The only thing we need to check whether $f(x)=x$ is a member of that space or not is to figure out whether $x$ is a polynomial or not. Since it is, the identity function is in the space.

Similarly for the space of all continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, or the space of *all* functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. In each case it's quick and easy to see that $f(x)=x$ is such a function and therefore in the space.

On the other hand, there's a space of all *bounded* functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ or all functions that have a finite limit for $x\to\infty$, and it is similarly easy to see that $f(x)=x$ doesn't satisfy those conditions and therefore is not in those particular spaces.

In neither of these cases do you have to check "11+ conditions" in order to find out whether the function is in a given space.

You do have to check a number of conditions in order to verify whether a particular set with such-and-such addition and multiplication operations *is a vector space at all* (or is a particularly nice kind of vector space), but you don't need to redo all that every time you want to determine whether a given function (or other object) is in the set or not.

Comment: Thank you, but can you clarify one thing for me. For example, I claim that $f(x) = x$ is an element of Hilbert space. To prove this claim, wouldn't I have to first check additivity, multiplicity, existence of inverse, identity, 0 element, linearity with respect to field,.... ... until I reach a conclusion that all is satisfied therefore $x$ is an element of hilbert space. Sort of tedious don't you think?

Comment: @MathNewb: There's no such thing as "is an element of Hilbert space". A Hilbert space is a particular _kind_ of vector space, but there are many different Hilbert spaces. Only once you have a _particular_ Hilbert space in mind can you ask whether $f(x)=x$ is one of its elements.

Comment: @MathNewb: All of those conditions you list are conditions _for something to be a vector space_. They are not conditions for something to be an _element_ of a vector space. You can quickly see that $f(x)=x$ is not a vector space (a vector space is a set together with an addition and multiplication operator, and $f(x)=x$ doesn't even look like that), but it can be an _element_ of a vector space. Each particular vector space will tell you how to recognize its elements.

Comment: For example, you can ask whether $f(x)=x$ is a member of the _particular_ Hilbert space of square integrable functions, for example. To test that, all you need is to answer one question: does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2\,dx$ exist or not? If yes, then the function is in that particular Hilbert space. If no, then it isn't. (It isn't).

Comment: I think I see it better now. Just one more thing, suppose $f(x)$ is a square integrable function, why do we need to know whether it is an element of Hilbert space or not?

Comment: @MathNewb: I don't know. _Do_ we need to know? If you have a reason for wanting to know, then I suppose whatever that reason is would count as a "need" for you, but I can't tell you what it would be. On the other hand, if you _don't_ have any reason to care whether the function is in the Hilbert space or not, then feel free not to care. It's not as if the math police is going to take you away and shoot you for remaining ignorant whether a random function is or isn't a member of a random Hilbert space.